# validate mathematical variables expression in java

Tags: java

Which is the good way to validate a mathematical variables expression. Whether we can use stack or with regex expression.

I have gone with http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-evaluate-expression-using-stacks/

Note: The expression does not contain parenthesis.
For example:

*Valid:*

- `x+3-y/2`
- `x+y`
- `2+4+e`

*Invalid:*

- `x++4+8`
- `e-3r`
- `e+r34-`

How to validate the above expressions?I need to validate the mathematic expression input provided by user in java

Comment: One option would be to use a stack, as is done with reverse polish notation.  By the way, `x++4+8` is not invalid if you accept `++` as being an increment operator.

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: I need to validate the mathematic expression input provided by user in java

Comment: Can input contain parentheses?

Comment: x++4+8 is a not a proper mathematic expression. Yes in java you can consider a increment operator, but we need to validate a mathematic expression

Comment: parentheses wont be allowed as input from user. Just the expression having varaiables and then we need to validate and then pass the values to respective variables

Comment: @bharathi unless you allow numbers to have a sign ('+') in this case. Btw. what was the problem when you used the linked program?

Comment: I will give you a mention , you can use stack to validation all operators so convert to postfix expression then check operator take two element  ... for parantesis you can use also stack if { encounter import into stack  until encounter }  but if there is no { but you encounter  with } error

Comment: suppose expression is H:"x + 234 * y * 4 - 2 / z", first I have to push the variables in stack and then check the expression is valid and then pass the input to the  x,y,z. and evaluate the result. My understanding is correct?

Comment: The source you have cited is identifiable as 100% drivel from about line 33 onwards. For example, it doesn't handle either parentheses or even binary minus. Have a look around for recursive descent expression parsers, or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Comment: Please, add no-parentheses-allowed condition to the question, so the readers will not be confused by the answer.

Comment: And now tell us *why* parentheses are not allowed. That's about the first question the users will ask. Don't implement arbitrary restrictions just to suit yourself. I've seen this sort of thing crash and burn too many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no parentheses (i.e. nesting expressions) are allowed, the validation could be done by simple regex:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+|[a-z]+)([-+*/]([0-9]+|[a-zAZ]+))*");

for (String s : Arrays.asList("123", "x+3-y/2", "x+y", "2+4+e", "x++4+8", "e-3r", "e+r34-", "---x+3-y/2")) {
    System.out.format("%5s %s\n", pattern.matcher(s).matches(), s);
}
```

The output is

```
 true 123
 true x+3-y/2
 true x+y
 true 2+4+e
false x++4+8
false e-3r
false e+r34-
false ---x+3-y/2
```

Comment: Thanks Kgeorgiy. This answer is really helpful for me to start the analysis. Can I know which one is better one to use  stack or with regex expression.Any idea?

Comment: failed on `---x+3-y/2`

Comment: Stack-based solution required when nesting expressions are allowed, but as this is not the case the regex solution is much more simplier.

Comment: @Aroniana As we see from examples, unary '+' is not allowed, so, probably, unary '-' should not be supported too.

Comment: @Aroniana It's pretty strange. I added `---x+3-y/2` to the test set and got `false`, as expected.

Comment: You cannot parse a context-free language with a regular-expression technique.

Comment: @EJP Without nesting expressions (i.e. parentheses) this language is regular

Comment: There is nothing in the question about not using parentheses.

Comment: To clarify all, This is a normal mathematic expression which we used solve it in school days. No preincrement and postincrement used here

Comment: @EJP See comments under the question itself. I've explicitly asked whether they are allowed and got the positive answer before posting my solution.